# Property tester does not work on second editor page

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I created an editor with two editor pages. I added tool bar items for the two pages with property testers. On the first page the property testers work fine. But if I open the editor, select the second page and select tree item, the property testers are not working. Manual requesting the evaluation of the property testers does not work. After selecting another view or a tree item on first page, the property testers work fine on second page too. Whats the problem? Here an example for editor:

```
public class MyEditor extends FormEditor {

    @Override
    protected void addPages() {
        try {
            addPage(new MyPage(this));
            addPage(new MyPage(this));
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void doSaveAs() {
        // nothing to do
    }

}

class MyPage extends FormPage {

    private static final String TOOLBAR_URI = "toolbar:my.page";

    public MyPage(final FormEditor editor) {
        super(editor, MyPage.class.getName(), "Test");
    }

    @Override
    protected void createFormContent(final IManagedForm managedForm) {

        final ScrolledForm form = managedForm.getForm();

        final ToolBarManager toolbarManager = (ToolBarManager) form.getToolBarManager();
        final IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) getSite().getService(IMenuService.class);
        menuService.populateContributionManager(toolbarManager, TOOLBAR_URI);

        final Composite body = managedForm.getForm().getBody();
        body.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(body);
        treeViewer.setContentProvider(new MyContentProvider());
        treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider());
        treeViewer.setInput(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "B", "C" }));

        getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);
    }

}

class MyContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(final Object inputElement) {
        return ((List<String>) inputElement).toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getChildren(final Object parentElement) {
        return new Object[] {};
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParent(final Object element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(final Object element) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(final Viewer viewer, final Object oldInput, final Object newInput) {
        // nothing to do
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
<handler
    class="EditHandler"
    commandId="myEdit">
    <activeWhen>
        <with
            variable="selection">
            <test
                property="my.active">
            </test>
        </with>
    </activeWhen>
</handler>
```

Property tester registration:

```
<propertyTester
    class="MyPropertyTester"
    id="MyPropertyTester"
    namespace="my"
    properties="active"
    type="java.lang.Object">
</propertyTester>
```

Property tester:

```
public class MyPropertyTester extends PropertyTester {

    public static final String ID = MyPropertyTester.class.getName();

    public static final String ACTIVE = "active";

    @Override
    public boolean test(final Object receiver, final String property, final Object[] args, final Object expectedValue) {

        if (receiver instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) receiver;
            if (selection.size() == 1) {
                return isMatch(property);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isMatch(final String property) {
        if (ACTIVE.equals(property)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the property tester is actually testing.

Comment: ok, I updated the question

Comment: With that property tester definition you should be testing `my.active` not `active`. You still haven't said what the property tester code is actually testing.

Comment: @greg-449 yes thank you, a very simple test does not work on second page, but the property tester is not called, so it does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" it via hack on editor page change:

```
@Override
protected void pageChange(int newPageIndex) {
    List<IWorkbenchPart> views = ... // find all opened IWorkbenchPart
    if (!views.isEmpty()) {
        views.get(0).setFocus();
        this.setFocus();
    }
    super.pageChange(newPageIndex);
}
```